# How to save reaction times to a visual stimulus into a csv file

Tags: python, csv, psychopy

I am VERY new and inexperienced with Python/coding in general. I am creating a Stroop task in python psychopy. I have created a functioning code to present the visual stimuli I need, I just need to work out how to save the participant's reaction times to each of the stimuli. I tried some code I found online and it gave me the reaction time in relation to the start of the experiment, not in terms of each stimulus presentation (this is what I want). Any help in this would be much appreciated. Plus I also need to record the trial number, colour of the text, name of the colour word, the colour the participant responded with, and whether they were correct or not onto the csv file also. Any help on this would be going beyond my initial question but also VERY helpful! :)

```
filename = 'stroop3data.csv'

f = open(filename, 'w')
csvfile = DictWriter(f, fieldnames = ['RT'])
csvfile.writeheader()

congruent_pairs = 15 * [('red', 'red'), ('blue', 'blue'), ('green',      'green'), ('yellow', 'yellow')]
incongruent_pairs = 5 * [('red', 'blue'), ('red', 'green'), ('red',   'yellow'), ('blue', 'red'), ('blue', 'green'), ('blue', 'yellow'), ('green', 'red'), ('green', 'blue'), ('green', 'yellow'), ('yellow', 'red'), ('yellow', 'blue'), ('yellow', 'green')]

pairs = congruent_pairs + incongruent_pairs



shuffle(congruent_pairs)
shuffle(incongruent_pairs)
shuffle(pairs)

answer_keys = {'f': 'red', 'g': 'blue', 'h': 'green', 'j': 'yellow'}

rts = []



win = visual.Window([1024, 768], fullscr = False, \
                allowGUI=True, units="pix", color = (-1, -1, -1))

stim = visual.TextStim(win)

instructionText = visual.TextStim(win, "Thank you for choosing to   participate in this experiment. You will be presented with different names of colours. In some trials the colour of the word will match the name of the colour, in some the colour of the word \
                              will be different to the name of the colour. Your task is to identify the colour of the word, ignoring the word itself. Coloured stickers on the keyboard in front of you correspond to the key you should press to indicate your response.\
                              \
                              \
                              PRESS 'ENTER' TO CONTINUE", color=(1,   1, 1))
instructionText.draw()

win.flip()

event.waitKeys(keyList=['return'])

readyText = visual.TextStim(win, "Ready?", color=(1, 1, 1))

readyText.draw()


win.flip()


event.waitKeys(keyList=['return'])



for pair in pairs:



    stim.text = pair[0]
    stim.color = pair[1]



    stim.draw()
    event.clearEvents()

    displaytime = win.flip()





    keys, rt = event.waitKeys(keyList=answer_keys.keys(), timeStamped=True)[0] 
    key, keytime = keys [0]
    rts.append(keytime - displaytime)




    score = answer_keys[key] == pair[1]#means that the correct answer corresponds to the colour of the word



    stim.text = 'CORRECT!' if score else 'INCORRECT'
    stim.text += '\nRT=%i ms' %(rt*1000)
    stim.draw()
    win.flip()
    event.waitKeys()

    csvfile.writerow({'RT': rts})
```

I have already tried altering the different names in the section where I save the keys and reaction times. All of the combinations I have tried cause many different errors... for example : 'float object not iterable', 'tuple object not iterable' - for line 93 (key time - display time), not enough arguments for the line above that, etc etc.

I would preferably like the reaction time to save as a float in seconds to my csv file.

Comment: I'd recommend you learn to use PsychoPy's `TrialHandler` class https://www.psychopy.org/api/data.html#psychopy.data.TrialHandler This will handle a lot of this work for you (i.e. it will read in your conditions from the csv file and automatically handle saving those variables to a data file). There is an `.addData()` function for incorporating measures you calculate (such as reaction times) into the data file. Other than that, there are a bunch of questions here: you might find that the community forum at https://discourse.psychopy.org is better suited to getting support..

Comment: Thank you for your help. Much appreciated!